# how to simultaneously run two cmd line using python(ngrok and localhost)?

Tags: python, cmd, server, command, ngrok

```
os.system('python -m http.server 8000')
os.system("ngrok http 8000")
```

The 'ngrok command' runs only after the above command, how to run both commands simultaneously?

I even tried to run it in different python file.

Answer (score 0):

Running two things truly simultaneously isn't possible based on the way instruction pipelines work at a computer architecture level.

If you want them to be run from one command, you can use &:

```
os.system('python -m http.server 8000 & ngrok http 8000")
```

This will run them concurrently in the same way you run commands concurrently in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the following a shot:

```
import subprocess

procs = [
    subprocess.Popen("python -m http.server 8000", shell=True),
    subprocess.Popen("ngrok http 8000", shell=True)
]

for proc in procs:
    proc.wait()
```

This will allow you to launch python processes and then wait for them to terminate.